# Using indexOf in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to use indexOf(" "); on this string

`"This i$ an aardvaAr yeEeeAs onDo qwerty XYZ9";`

this is my code

```
        space = word.indexOf(" ");

        tempWord = word.substring(0, space);
```

Now I get what I want which is `This` string but now how do I get the next space which has this after it:`i$`, and the next one unitl the end of the string?

***EDIT**

Please no arrays for this question

Comment: It would be better to split the `String` using `String[] substringsNoSpace = word.split(" ");`

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention, I cant use arrays

Comment: Any other limitation for the solution? Could you use `java.util.Scanner` or `java.util.regex.Pattern` or just `String` class methods?

Comment: This has to look like a first year project, so it better to keep it simple

Comment: `java.util.Scanner` is for first year project, so it's up to you indeed. Also, you can always add results of further investigation to your project only if you demonstrate that you understand the proposed solution :).

Comment: yes we have used `java.util.Scanner`, I have also used regex for few simple things but we haven't covered those

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [overload of `indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) which takes the starting index too:

```
int nextSpace = word.indexOf(" ", space + 1);
```

(Although there may very well be a better approach to your bigger problem.)

Comment: That is what I like, an nice quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to split the string (and create an String array) you can read the rest of the string after hitting the first space (btw. this seems like a schoolwork on recursive functions):

```
int space = test.indexOf(" ");
String before = test.substring(0, space);
String after = test.substring(space + 1);
```